# custom SeekBar is overlapping or disappearing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, seekbar

Does any one know how to fix this problem of mine were my seek-bar thumb disappears upon reaching the end of the bar or overlaps the bar when i use padding. I have customized my seek-bar to suit the way i wish it to. However when i scroll the thumb to each extreme end be it left or right it either overlaps the progress bar or disappears into the progress bar depending on the amount of padding i set. But i wish it so that when the right or left side of the thumb touches the right or left side respectively of the seek-bar it stops. Not disappear so that the thumb is not visible or overlap so that the thumb appears off the progress bar. Here is my code.

Seek-bar code

```
<SeekBar
          android:id="@+id/seekbartemperature"
          android:layout_width="415dp"
          android:layout_height="12dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
          android:max="1000"
          android:paddingLeft="7dp"
          android:paddingRight="7dp"
          android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
          android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable" />
```

background fill

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <!-- <size android:height="1000dp" android:width="900dp"/>-->
<gradient 
    android:startColor="#FFDBDBDB" 
    android:centerColor="#FFDBDBDB"
    android:endColor="#FFDBDBDB" 
     />


</shape>
```

progress fill

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <gradient 
    android:startColor="#FF21539E" 
    android:centerColor="#FF21539E"
    android:endColor="#FF21539E" 
     />
    <padding
    android:left="100dp"
    android:right="100dp"/>


 </shape>
```

seek-bar thumb drawable

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#ff353535" android:endColor="#ff353535" android:angle="0"/>
<size android:height="13dp" android:width="13dp"/>
<padding android:left="70dp" android:right="70dp"/>
<corners android:radius="0px"/>
   <!-- <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#353535" />-->
</shape>
```

progress bar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item 
            android:id="@android:id/background" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill" />

        <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
           <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
        </item>  

</layer-list>
```

As i said guys i have tried using padding as you can see in the seek-bar code. Using 7dp at the moment is making the disappearing/overlapping of the thumb less noticeable. I have also tried adding padding to the progress, thumb and background fill but no effect. Giving more or less padding makes it worst so is there anything i am not doing or how do i make this work to my specifications?

Comment: how do you do that sir elaborate please thank you

Comment: call setThumbOffset()